# iOS app runs slow after some time of using

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, performance, instruments

I am working on a heavy UI-based Application on which there are a lot of animations and observers put on, the view of the app is dynamic so I need to draw views runtime after getting a response which is also about 3-4 MBs.

What is currently happening is I parse the JSON in the background queue render views in the main queue, now these views work fine but only for a while after which it becomes very difficult to even navigate for example pressing the back button performs API call parses the response and then takes more one minute to navigate to the previous screen

What I have tried:

1. Solved all memory leaks (ie. all my view controllers' `deinit`s are called)
2. Cached images wherever needed

I am looking for a direction to look at for detecting the issue, I have tried using the Instruments. It has the highest weight at the method in which I parse the response, I have a variable in which I have put the reload in didSet, In this method, it runs a loop and tries to identify the type of view which should be rendered in the screen.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi @nimbus  welcome to SO! I think your question looks interesting, but it could be helpful to add the relevant networking code.